# Trying to proxy HTTPS, but getting: An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: nginx

There is a HTTPS server on one port (5006). I'd like to make it available on 35001 and serve other things on the same 35001 too (by adding locations like `/app`, `/auth`, `/admin`, etc.).

Server is `auth-server.org.local`. Trying just to add a port:

```
server {
    listen 35001;
    location / {
        proxy_pass       https://auth-server.org.local:5006;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ curl -k -X GET https://auth-server.org.local:5006
<h1>My auth server</h1>

$ curl -k -X GET https://auth-server.org.local:35001
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

Why 35001 doesn't work? What am I missing? I've used this guide: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-https-upstreams/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your virtual server is a HTTP server, therefore it doesn't work with https connection attempts.

In order to make it HTTPS, you need to have this configuration:

```
server {
    listen 35001 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl/certificate;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://auth-server.local:5006;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can set up an nginx `stream` proxy, which simply passes the TCP stream to backend, so that nginx does not perform SSL termination:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 35001;
        proxy_pass auth-server.local:5006;
    }
}
```

This has to be outside the `http` context.